# Maximum sum subarray with the length smaller than k problem . O(n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have encountered this problem in an olympiad and im really struggling to find the solution, bc the hint is not really descriptive enough. Please help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the full problem and examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first, we need an array of cumulative sums.  Now finding the subarray that we want is just a question of finding the two points no more than `k` apart whose values have the largest difference.

To solve that second problem we will need a helper array of the minimum cumulative sums within the last `k`.  Or more precisely to hold tuples of `(value, position)`  And now here is pseudocode:

```
calculate cumulative sums array
initialize best subarray to be first choice
initialize minimum helper array to have just the first choice
for each position in cumulative sums array:
    if first in helper array to here is better than best subarray:
        update best subarray
    while last in minimum helper array >= this value:
        pop() last from minimum helper array
    insert this at end of minimum helper array
    if first in helper array is k before this:
        remove first in helper array
```

This algorithm is `O(n)`.  To see that, first note that all array operations on the helper array are amortized `O(1)`.  And associated for each position we have at most the following operations (executed slightly out of order):

```
add value to running total for cumulative sum array
potentially update best subarray discovered so far
be compared with some later element and removed
    (that happens on a later loop, but only once for this position)
be compared with an earlier element that is smaller than this
be inserted into helper array
potentially be removed from the start of the helper array.
```

Every one of those operations are `O(1)`.  Since there are `n` positions, the whole algorithm is `O(n)`.